# Reformat timestamp in org-capture-template

Tags: org-mode

I cloned such a template

```
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
             '("d" "Diary"
               entry (file "~/ORG/src/diary.org")
               "* %u \n** Log\n\n*** Tasks\n\n** Creating Writing" ;;heading必须要紧跟在\n\n后面.
               :empty-lines 1
               )
             )
```

It display the timestamp as

```
[2019-07-09 Tue]
** Log

** Creative Writing
```

How could re-format the timestamp as

```
Tue Jul-09
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I typed `C-h v` (aka `M-x describe-variable`) and then `org-capture-templates` ....  A cursory review of the doc-string led me to an interesting entry as follows:  "**%<...>      The result of format-time-string on the ... format specification.**"  So, now we can look up the function `format-time-string` -- `C-h f` (aka `M-x describe-function`) and see how to customize the output ...

Here is a snippet of a component of my customization of `org-capture-templates`:

```
DEADLINE: <%<%Y-%m-%d %a>>
```

which gives me ... `DEADLINE: <2019-07-08 Mon>` ... assuming that is the current date when creating the task/event.

Comment: changed it to ` "* <%a %b-%d\n>** Log\n\n*** Tasks\n\n** Creative w", but it does not work.

Comment: Does this work?:  `<%<%a %b-%d>>\n`

Comment: amazing , it works perfectly.

Comment: The `org-capture.el` library uses a hard-coded regular expression matching forms described in the doc-string of `org-capture-templates` -- in older versions of `org-mode`, the regexp looks like `"%<\\([^>\n]+\\)>"` and `"%\\([tTuUaliAcxkKInfF]\\)"`.  In newer versions of `org-mode`, the regexp looks like `"%\\(:[-a-za-z]+\\|<\\([^>\n]+\\)>\\|[aAcfFikKlntTuUx]\\)"`.  By using a particular format when customizing `org-capture-templates` that will match the hard-coded regexp in `org-capture.el`, the desired result can be achieved ....

Comment: ty for the detailed tutorial.